# Importing textscan

Tags: textscan

I have a large CSV data and I tried to import using textscan. The data has some letters NA in the inside the data. I used the following script, however out of 215842 rows only 11 are recognized. The data importing stopped at row where it encouter the NA text.

How could I convert this data to NaN before importing to matlab or other alternative to that might work?

```
field=fopen ('wt01.csv');

  wt_data= textscan (field,' %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f ','delimiter',',');

fclose (field);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the TreatAsEmpty option, like `wt_data= textscan(fid,' %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f ','delimiter',',','TreatAsEmpty',{'NA','na'});`

See http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html

Or use `uiimport` as it will give you nice buttons to press, including what to do with data that doesn't match the ideal format, and later allow you to generate a script from it, so that you can reuse it.

Comment: That is great and thank you. before reading your message I replaced the NA by some number 99999 outside matlab then I able to import.

Comment: I am sorry D.S, I thought I accepted the answer, the problem is I am not much familar. I hope now accepted otherwise tell me again .

Comment: It isn't marked as accepted. I sadly can't help much with that though, as I haven't asked a question myself yet and thus don't know what the interface looks like, but perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) or [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow)  can help

Comment: Thank you, now I found it, and it is simple, just click on the gray tick sign to the left of the down facing arrow.